# How to add `systemProperties` to IOT Central Message

Tags: azure, powerbi, iot, azure-iot-central

I've been trying to follow the '[Visualize and analyze your Azure IoT Central data in a Power BI dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-connect-powerbi)' tutorial to display data from Azure IoT Central in Power BI. However, when I open the file generated by the '[Power BI Solution for Azure IoT Central V3](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en/product/web-apps/iot-central.power-bi-solution-iot-central)', the tables and graphs are present, but nothing is populated.

This is some information and steps I have taken to try and solve this:

- My first idea is that the message does not have `contentType:application/JSON` or `contentEncoding:utf-8` in the `systemProperties` header in the message (like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-routing-query-syntax#message-routing-query-based-on-message-properties)). I think this may be a problem because when I go to download raw data from the storage blob, I don't see the `systemProperties` or `messages` headers (I've attached a sample of what I do see below). I've looked around but I don't see how I would add these headers to message through IoT Central.
- I looked at the SQL database generated by the solution, and it appears there is no information being passed to it. I checked this by selecting 'Power BI (preview)' in the side menu of the SQL database.
- I have waited a few hours and the table and graphs are still not populated so I don't think it's a time lag issue.

Any help would be great!

Sample storage blob data:

```
{"messageSource":"telemetry","telemetry":{"humidity":41.44,"temperature":30.34,"pressure":892.51},"schema":"default@v1","messageProperties":{},"enrichments":{},"applicationId":"72236ce8-5edf-493f-8b9d-a7cef16c20bc","deviceId":"jasper","enqueuedTime":"2021-07-16T20:12:54.729Z","templateId":"urn:modelDefinition:p08bqguhitr:xryhwfwxqgp"}...
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [tutorial document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-connect-powerbi), there are [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-central/core/howto-connect-powerbi#prerequisites) where your devices must send JSON encoded messages (contentType:application/JSON and contentEncoding:utf-8).

In the case of MQTT device, add the following properties on the topic:

```
$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8
```

example:

```
devices/mydeviceId/messages/events/$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8
```